# Displaying submitted form results as a list of URL links

Tags: php, mysql, forms

First of all my PHP skills are kinda limited, Hence my question to you here.
I have built a fairly complex form with multiple inputs(text boxs and drop downs) which are stored in a MYsql DB. When the form is submitted it displays on a new page as completed reports. These completed reports display one under the next every time the form is submitted. My question is, How can i get the reports displayed to show as a list of links to the individual reports rather then a list of complete reports.
I hope i've explained the situation well enough.

```
Code snippit from viewpage.php


<html>
<head>

<body>

<?php
                mysql_connect("localhost","user","passwrd");
                mysql_select_db("dtbase");
                $order = "SELECT * FROM jobrequest" ;
                $result = mysql_query($order);
                while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){


?>          
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
<div style="padding:15px 0px 0px 100px;">
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0"  style="vertical-align:middle;width: 1139px; background-color:#213568; height:36px;">
    <tr>
        <td class="topbar">Client Request Form</td>
        <td style="width:900px;"></td>
        <td class="topbar"><a style="color:#ffffff;" href="logout.php?logout">Logout</a></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<div class="main-wrap">
<div class="content">
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0"  style="width: 1137px; background-color:#ffffff; height:5px;">
    <tr>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" >
    <tr>
                                <td style="vertical-align:top; width:5px;"></td>
         <td style="vertical-align:top;"><?php include("includes/clientchoices.php"); ?></td>
        <td style="vertical-align:top; padding:0px 5px 15px 5px;">
                <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                <tr>
                                <td style="vertical-align:top; width:1002px;"> <h1> Dashboard</h1></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                                <td style="vertical-align:top; background-color:#f5f5f5;"><h2>Job Request Form</h2></td>
                </tr>
                  <tr>
                                <td style="vertical-align:top; background-color:#ffffff; height:5px;"> </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                                <td>
                    <div class="form">
                    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="width:998px">
                         <tr>
                            <td style="width:1002px; border:solid 1px #000000; padding:10px 0px 10px 0px;"><center><img src="../../images/spectra_logotop.jpg" alt="Spectra" title="Spectra" width="735" height="120" style="padding:5px;"></center>
                            </td>
                         </tr>
                         <tr>  
                            <td>
                                <div style="padding:10px 0px 10px 0px;">
                                    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td class="headingsa">Project Leader:</td><td class="answersa"><div class= "typesectiona"><?php echo ($row['project_leader'] ); ?></div></td>
                                            <td class="headingsb">Contact Number:</td><td class="answersb"><div class= "typesectionb"><?php echo ($row['contact_number'] ); ?></div></td>
                                            <td class="headingsc">Company Details:</td><td class="answersc"><div class= "typesectionc"><?php echo ($row['company_details'] ); ?></div></td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                               </div>
                          </td>
                         </tr>
                         <tr>  
                            <td>
                                <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td class="headings5">Contact Person On Site:</td><td class="answers5"><div class= "typesection5"><?php echo ($row['contactperson_onsite'] ); ?></div></td>
                                        <td class="headings6">Contact Details:</td><td class="answers6"><div class= "typesection6"><?php echo ($row['contact_no'] ); ?></div></td>
                                        <td class="headings7">Date:</td><td class="answers7"><div class= "typesection7"><?php echo ($row['date'] ); ?></div></td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </td>  
                         </tr>
                         <tr>  
                            <td>
                                <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td class="headings1">Job/Order Number:</td><td class="answers1"><div class= "typesection1"><?php echo ($row['job_order_number'] ); ?></div></td>
                                        <td class="headings2">Document Number:</td><td class="answers2"><div class= "typesection2"><?php echo ($row['doument_number'] ); ?></div></td>
                                        <td class="headings3">QCP:</td><td class="answers3"><div class= "typesection3"><?php echo ($row['qcp'] ); ?></div></td>
                                        <td class="headings4">Page No:</td><td class="answers4"><div class= "typesection4"><?php echo ($row['pageno'] ); ?></div></td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </td>
                        </tr>

                    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
                        <tr>

                            <td width="15px"></td>
                            <td><a class="othersubmitsLink" href="actionpdf.php">Email to Spectra</a></td>
                        </tr>                                         
                    </table>
                    </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
         </td>           
    </tr>
</table>  
</div>
</div>
</div>
<?php
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What effort u make so far, any code snippet?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I generally do use mysqli rather then mysql. However in this case i am working on an existing mysql DB and didnt want to mess with the existing code. I did however find a solution to my problem. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need a separate PHP script for displaying a report based on a supplied ID.  This separate script would look something like this:

**Using mysqli**

```
<?php
    $conn = new mysqli("localhost", "user", "passwrd", "dtbase");
    $jrQry = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM jobrequest WHERE jobrequest_id = ?");
    $jrQry->bind_param('i', $_GET['jobrequest_id']);
    $jrQry->execute();
    $jobrequestResult = $jrQry->get_result();
    $jobrequest = $jobrequestResult->fetch_assoc();

    // At this point, $jobrequest will contain the jobrequest record you want to display.
?>
<!-- HTML FOR REPORT GOES HERE, USING $jobrequest VARIABLE TO SHOW THE DATA -->
```

Note that I have used mysqli in this example, if this is unsuitable you *can* use the old-style mysql commands, but for many many reasons (security chief among them) I would strongly suggest against this.

**Using mysql**

```
<?php
    mysql_connect("localhost","user","passwrd");
    mysql_select_db("dtbase");
    $order = "SELECT * FROM jobrequest WHERE jobrequest_id = " . (int)$_GET['jobrequest_id'];
    $result = mysql_query($order);
    $jobrequest = mysql_fetch_array($result);

    // At this point, $jobrequest will contain the jobrequest record you want to display.
?>
<!-- HTML FOR REPORT GOES HERE, USING $jobrequest VARIABLE TO SHOW THE DATA -->
```

Save this page as "viewjobrequest.php" and you will be able to load a given job request's report by supplying the jobrequest ID as a parameter in the URL, like so:

```
http://address_of_site/viewjobrequest.php?jobrequest_id=X
```

Now you can automatically generate a list of links to these pages by looking up your complete set of jobrequests and iterating over them, but instead on outputting a full report, just output a link:

**Using mysqli**

```
<?php
    $conn = new mysqli("localhost", "user", "passwrd", "dtbase");
    $jrQry = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM jobrequest WHERE jobrequest_id = ?");
    $jrQry->bind_param('i', $_GET['jobrequest_id']);
    $jrQry->execute();
    $jobrequestResult = $jrQry->get_result();
?>
    <ul>
<?php
    while ($jobrequest = $jobrequestResult->fetch_assoc())
    {
?>    
      <li>
        <a href="viewjobrequest.php?jobrequest_id=<?php echo $jobrequest['jobrequest_id']; ?>">
          View job request #<?php echo $jobrequest['jobrequest_id']; ?>
        </a>
      </li>
<?php
    }
?>
    </ul>
```

**Using mysql**

```
<?php
    mysql_connect("localhost","user","passwrd");
    mysql_select_db("dtbase");
    $order = "SELECT * FROM jobrequest WHERE jobrequest_id = " . (int)$_GET['jobrequest_id'];
    $result = mysql_query($order);
?>
    <ul>
<?php
    while ($jobrequest = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
?>    
      <li>
        <a href="viewjobrequest.php?jobrequest_id=<?php echo $jobrequest['jobrequest_id']; ?>">
          View job request #<?php echo $jobrequest['jobrequest_id']; ?>
        </a>
      </li>
<?php
    }
?>
    </ul>
```

*Note: I have deliberately omitted large portions of your HTML, you can add as much extra HTML as you need, I've just offered the bare bones to get you started.*

Answer (score 0):

BY looking at your code, I can say, it's not problem with PHP, it's more like HOW you are showing the result after fetching from database,

you are running loop, started from here

```
<?php while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){ ?>
```

and ends here

```
<?php}?>
```

So everything inside loop or in easy words inside these brackets `{}` repeating again and again with new row of result fetched from database, if you take view source of `viewpage.php` you will see that `style css` file `<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" />` repeating, Imagine if you are fetching 10 rows of result, you are also loading `css` file 10 times.

So the answer (most probably the solution) of your question is;

Your mysql query

```
<?php
            mysql_connect("localhost","user","passwrd");
            mysql_select_db("dtbase");
            $order = "SELECT * FROM jobrequest" ;
            $result = mysql_query($order);
            $totalrows = mysql_num_rows($result); //Check Total Number of Rows To Check if Data Exist or Not
?>
```

and then in your HTML, First check if there are any rows exist in database which match your `WHERE` clause in mysql query.

```
//Set an if else statement here so incase if no data exist.
<?php if($totalrows > 0) {
//If row(s) exist run your while loop here
     <?php while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){ ?>
     //Show the result here from database

     //Close your loop
     <?php } ?>
//Close your if condition
<?php } else { ?>
    //Display a message here if there is no data to show

    //Close your else bracket
<?php } ?>
```

With above explaniation I adjusted your HTML to show the result in desired way;

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="width:998px">
     <tr>
        <td style="width:1002px; border:solid 1px #000000; padding:10px 0px 10px 0px;"><center><img src="../../images/spectra_logotop.jpg" alt="Spectra" title="Spectra" width="735" height="120" style="padding:5px;"></center></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>  
        <td>
            <?php if($totalrows > 0) {
            <div style="padding:10px 0px 10px 0px;">
                <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                    <tr>
                        <td class="headingsa">Link to Report</td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){ ?>
                    <tr>
                    //You have to replace `nameoffile.php` with file in which you want to display report and correct this (as i assumed it) if it's wrong `$row['id']`
                        <td><a href="nameoffile.php?id=<?php echo $row['id'];?>">Open Report</a></td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php } ?>
                </table>
           </div>
           <?php } else { ?>
            <div style="padding:10px 0px 10px 0px;">
                <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                    <tr>
                        <td>There is No Result To Show</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
           </div>
           <?php } ?>
        </td>
    </tr>                                         
</table>
```

**Note:** MySQL will soon be deprecated, consider start using MYSQLi or PDO

Comment: This answer does not do what the OP requested, which is to display a list of links that each link to a copy of the populated report for that particular submission.

Comment: i corrected the answer and hope i do it correctly this time. thanks for pointing out